# data must be a two dimensional array of cellable objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, prawn

I'm trying to print some data in a table using a condition, but it returns the following error: data must be a two dimensional array of cellable objects

```
data = [["Lançamento"]]
data += @lancamentos.map do |lancamento|
  if lancamento.tipo == 'DESPESA'
    [
      lancamento.descricao_lancamento, lancamento.valor
    ]
  end
end
pdf.table data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empty mapped cells should be eliminated explicitly:

```
data = [["Lançamento"]]
data += (
  @lancamentos.map do |lancamento|
    if lancamento.tipo == 'DESPESA'
      [lancamento.descricao_lancamento, lancamento.valor]
    end          
  end.compact # ⇐ HERE
)

pdf.table data
```

Comment: Does precedence really matter here? I get the same result for both, `do ... end` and `{ ... }`

Comment: @Stefan indeed, I have re-checked, here it does not matter. I was under the impression it always matters, and I always put parentheses around `do-end` due to `puts %w|a b c|.map do |e| e end` `#⇒ #<Enumerator:0x00000003b29168>`.

Answer (score 0):

> it returns the following error: `data must be a two dimensional array of cellable objects`

You get this error because your `data` array contains `nil` values.

Consider this example:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map { |i| [i] if i.odd? }
#=> [[1], nil, [3], nil, [5]]
```

Whereas you want `[[1], [3], [5]]`.

Since you already have a `data` variable, you could use `each` instead of `map`:

```
data = [["Lançamento"]]
@lancamentos.each do |lancamento|
  if lancamento.tipo == 'DESPESA'
    data << [lancamento.descricao_lancamento, lancamento.valor]
  end
end
pdf.table data
```

Or you could use a combination of `select` and `map`:

```
data = @lancamentos.select { |l| l.tipo == 'DESPESA' }
                   .map    { |l| [l.descricao_lancamento, l.valor] }

table([ ['Lançamento'], *data ])
```